# Two SELECT statements in one stored procedure, one supplying input for another and the other returning more than one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement that gets 4 column values in a row for one iteration from a query that has lot of joins. One of the column value has to be given to another select statement as input to check a where condition. This select statement returns three rows for a input from each iteration of the first select statement. I need to get all the column values from the three rows of the second select statement along with the all the column values of the first select statement.

```
SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4 from ....

SELECT val5, val6 from anotherTable where someColumn = val1
```

RESULT required :

```
val1, val2, val3, val4, val51, val61, val52, val62, val53, val63
```

I, am using two connections and two readers to make this happen, but its slowing me down. I'd like it if I can get this done in a single stored procedure.

Comment: Have you ever before heard about `pivot`?

Comment: i guess another option will be to use a CTE or SUBQUERY

Comment: @abatishchev, no I haven't. Not so exp'd with sql. Can I get a rough idea in terms of query?

Comment: @sunilmat I updated my answer specifically for a SQLServer2005+ version. You should try it;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
WITH first AS 
(
  SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4
    FROM Table1
   WHERE 1 = 1
), second AS
(
  SELECT val1,
         MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN val5 END) val51,
         MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN val6 END) val61,
         MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN val5 END) val52,
         MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN val6 END) val62,
         MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 3 THEN val5 END) val53,
         MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 3 THEN val6 END) val63
    FROM
  (
    SELECT t2.val1, val5, val6, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.val1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rnum
      FROM Table2 t2 JOIN first f
        ON t2.val1 = f.val1
  ) a
   GROUP BY val1
)
SELECT * 
  FROM first f JOIN second s
    ON f.val1 = s.val1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09fd7/11)** demo

Comment: Firstly, sorry for replying late. Well I went on with doing another select in the loop where I read data from the first select. But I'd like to try this out. Could you tell me what's happening with this, also will this work in SQLServer 2005?

Comment: @sunilmat I don't have SQL Server 2005 at hand to try, but I believe it should work just fine. Now the first query in CTE just a normal select. In the inner select of the second query we assign row numbers partitioned by val1 and then in outer select pivot them into one row. Finally we just join two CTE's on val1.

Comment: val5 and val6, the columns in the second table are of type ntext.

Comment: I can mail you the actual query for you to have a look at, if you can mail me your id.

Comment: @sunilmat You can just put it in http://pastebin.com and post a link here. And make sure to post sample data with it. Otherwise it won't make any sense.

Comment: was the paste any good for you to process without the sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Example for SQLServer2005+

First part of the script combines result of the query into a single variable. Thus we have a names of columns in a PIVOT statement.

```
   DECLARE @cols varchar(100),
            @dml nvarchar(max)
    SET @cols = N''
    SELECT @cols += ',[val5' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS varchar(10)) + '],' 
                  + '[val6' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS varchar(10)) + ']'
    FROM (
          SELECT TOP 1 t.someColumn
          FROM dbo.test138 t
          GROUP BY t.someColumn
          ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
          ) t2 JOIN dbo.test138 t3 ON t2.someColumn = t3.someColumn
```

The second part of the instruction dynamically creates SQL, and then use this command.

```
SET @dml = 
 'SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT t1.val1, t1.val2, t1.val3, t1.val4, 
               COALESCE(o2.colName5, o2.colName6) AS colName, 
               COALESCE(o2.val5, o2.val6) AS val
        FROM dbo.test137 t1 CROSS APPLY (
                                         SELECT ''val5'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS varchar(10)), t2.val5, 
                                                ''val6'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS varchar(10)), t2.val6
                                         FROM dbo.test138 t2
                                         WHERE t1.val1 = t2.someColumn                                 
                                         ) o(colName5, val5, colName6, val6)
                            CROSS APPLY (
                                         SELECT o.colName5, NULL, o.val5, NULL
                                         UNION ALL
                                         SELECT NULL, o.colName6, NULL, o.val6
                                         ) o2(colName5, colName6, val5, val6)
        ) x
  PIVOT
 (
  MAX(x.val) FOR colName IN (' + STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '') + ')
  ) pvt'
--PRINT @dml
EXEC sp_executesql @dml
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aea56/2)

Comment: I think this will help me get it done. I'll mark it as answer as soon as I try this out with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out if ur return value are only 1 and u just want to use val1 as your second query parameter

```
DECLARE @val1 NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4 from ....

SET @val1 = (Select ordinal_position from information_schema.columns
where Column_Name='@val1' and Table_name = '@yourTableName')

SELECT val5, val6 from anotherTable where someColumn = @val1
```

Your return result

```
val1, val2, val3, val4, val51, val61, val52, val62, val53, val63
```

The return result is based on what u select, in this case, your 2nd query may not work

try to change ur 2nd query to something like below

```
Select val1,val2,val3, val4, COALESCE(val5,val1), COALESCE(val6,val1)
```

Comment: This is kind of what I needed, something simple which I can understand. Can you give me a more comprehensive answer. If possible a SQLFiddle. Thanks

Comment: despite typos, this is the correct answer, illustrating passing params back and forth, the OP was asking about `Stored Procedures` not giant encapsulated `subselects` (that *merely happen* to be created as stored procedures), there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

to put meat on the bones of this you do it like this

```
Create PROCEDURE GetInfo(
  @Search_For varchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @val1 NVARCHAR(255)
    SET  @val1 = (SELECT MAX(StoredDate) FROM my_archive)
    SELECT line_id, site_code, StoredDate=@val1 FROM line WHERE LineCode=@Search_For 
END
```

where

```
 my_archive *contains
+------------------------------+
| StoredDate

line *contains
+------------------------------+
| line_id, site_code, LineCode
```

gives you

```
line_id  site_code   StoredDate
1        SF          Jan 18 2018  1:07PM
```